# How do I get a specific colorcolumn value?

Tags: colorcolumn

I've discovered the wonder that is `colorcolumn` but I haven't yet mastered the black art of Vim scripting. If I have `:set colorcolumn=80,132` in my .vimrc, how can I a) discover that I have more than one value, and b) access that 2nd value?

I have a line completion function that uses `&cc` to calculate a padding value:

```
function! LinePadOut(c)
  exec 'norm A ^['.(&cc - virtcol('$')).'A'.nr2char(a:c)
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <C-L><C-L> ':call LinePadOut('.getchar().')^M'
```

This only takes into consideration the "80." How can I get at the "132" or even know it's there? I'd like to write a "long padding" version that uses the 132.
(I take *no credit* for this function. It was someone else's magic that I poked at until it did what I wanted.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One strange thing about vimscript is that it automatically converts string to numbers when some
operations are applied.
For example, if you try this:

```
if '123foo'
    echo 'hi'
endif
```

You will get 'hi' as the output, but if you try this:

```
if 'foo'
    echo 'hi'
endif
```

You will get nothing.

This happens because the condition of an 'if' sentence has to be an int, so both strings are
automatically converted likewise and we get 123 and 0 respectively because the conversion stops
at any non digit char.

The value stored in colorcolumn option is a string as stated in the help (see 'colorcolumn'),
specifically a comma separate list of values with the type string that contain the column
numbers that are highlighted.

Just like 'if' sentence, the minus sign '-' requires numbers to be its operands and strings will
be converted (until first non digit) in order to accomplish that.
So when you do:

```
&cc - virtcol('$')
```

The value of &cc which is originally "80,132" automatically converts to 80
losing the 132 and any other value.
If you want to treat all the separated values, I would recommend you to split the contents of
colorcolumn with the split() function:

```
let value_list = split(&cc, ',') " Split values at ,
```

Then, you can use a for statement to treat all the values. You can also query the length by
using the len() function:

```
for value in value_list
    echo 'The value is: ' . value
endfor

let number_of_values = len(value_list)

for i in range(number_of_values)
    echo 'The value in ' . i . ' position is: ' . value_list[i]
endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I a) discover that I have more than
>   one value, and b) access that 2nd value?

a). By checking if the option contains a comma. I'd do so with a regular expression comparison. See [`:help =~`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-=~):

```
if &cc =~ ','
  echo 'Multiple colorcolumns'
endif
```

b). By splitting the option's value on the comma(s). See [`:help split()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#split()):

```
for cc in split(&cc, ',')
  echo 'colorcolumn:' cc
endfor
```

c). To explain why your code ignores the second
colorcolumn in your setting, note that `&cc`
is not a `Number` but in fact a `String`:

```
:echo type(&cc) == type("")
```

(See also [:help 'colorcolumn'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27colorcolumn%27).)

So when you attempt to subtract from it, it
is converted into a `Number` with the
following technique:

> Conversion from a String to a Number is done by converting the first digits
>   to a number.

—[`:help Number`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#Number)

Thus, everything after and including the
first comma is ignored.